# django-rest-framework there is no autogenerated form in the BrowsableAPi while using viewsets and routes?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Kindly assist on this. I cant seem to get the HTML form in the browsable API for django rest. I figured its coz its no the default behaviour while using genericViews. But while using Viewsets the HTML form on the BrowsableApi is not available.What would be problem? How do i include the HTML form into the Browsable Api?

Comment: show your urls.py file.

Comment: `from rest_framework import routers
from django.conf.urls import url
from .views import (
    UploadViewSet
)
router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'uploads', UploadViewSet)

urlpatterns = router.urls`


Thats how i am wiring up my urls, with the main url patterns being within the projects main urls.py file.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I really dont think the problem is with the url patterns, because i can route to the page seemlessly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are viewing the result page but the form isn't shown:

- make sure you have enough permissions to create/update items
- make sure you are using a ModelViewSet or have included the `mixins.UpdateModelMixin` and/or `mixins.CreateModelMixin`
- make sure you have the `MultiPartParser` and/or `FormParser`

Comment: I am using the ModelViewSet
 `from rest_framework.viewset`
I will try and include the MultipartParsers and FormParsers.

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much @Linovia adding the appropriate Parsershas worked.

Answer (score 0):

@Linovia Your solution worked just fine. The problem was missing the correct parser in the project to render the forms. I included both parsers.